# TinyMCE autocloses a-tags and/or rearranges them

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using the template option of the tinyMCE plugin. I'm loading in a template which works fine, however at the bottom of the page I see something not behaving correctly; some a-tags with i-tags inside of them are becoming rearranged. This causes the view to ends up looking differently than the template intended.

When I click the template and see it in the preview-window, I see everything the way it was arranged in the template and so I'm assuming the code is correct in the template-preview-window. However, once I click 'OK' and the template is being added to the HTMLEditor-window, It's not being rendered correctly. What I've already tried is to make TinyMCE not validate my HTML by adding this;

```
valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

to my tinymce.init() function (which did help with similar issues I experienced before, just not this one).

This code (coming from the template that I load in);

```
<h3 class="section-title">
            <span> BRAND</span> 
            <a id="nextBrand" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a> 
            <a id="prevBrand" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        </h3>
```

Becomes this code after adding the template to the tinyMCE HTML-Editor;

```
<h3 class="section-title">
<span> BRAND</span> 
<a id="nextBrand" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"></a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
<a id="prevBrand" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"></a><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
</h3>
```

And so as you can see, the a-tag is being closed automatically and the i-tag is being added after it, which makes it look weird and obviously the anchor won't work anymore.

Any idea's as to how I can work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In TinyMCE, `<a>` tags with no `href` attribute are considered anchors, and by default,  anchors are collapsed and the children get moved out of the anchor.

This default behavior can be disabled with this option:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#allow_html_in_named_anchor

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.